# Add image to SVG element in dart

Tags: dart, dart-html

I am trying to show an (interchangeable) image as background to an ellipse or other various things I will manipulate later.
The problem is that I can't find how to load the image properly.

My code:

```dart
DivElement div = querySelector("#mainDiv");
svg.SvgElement svgElement = new svg.SvgSvgElement();
div.append(svgElement);
//div.setAttribute("background-color", "yellow");

svg.RectElement rec = new svg.RectElement();
rec.setAttribute("x", "0");
rec.setAttribute("y", "0");
rec.setAttribute("width",div.clientWidth.toString());
rec.setAttribute("height", div.clientHeight.toString());
//svgElement.children.add(rec);  

Ellipse ell = new Ellipse() //my class. shows and allow to move it
..cx = 100
..cy= 100
..rx= 50
..ry= 50;
svgElement.children.add(ell.ellipse);
ImageElement image = new ImageElement(src: "2.jpg");
image.onLoad.listen((e) {
  svgElement.children.add(image);
});
```

As you can see there is a Rectangle, which was my first attempt to show the image with various attributes (background-image, background..), then I thought to add the ImageElement directly after onLoad. Both Failed.

My next step should be to try with patterns, but I'm not sure if I can translate in Dart what I've read for javascript.

Edit: It would be nice to be able to load the image as well, so that I can read attributes like dimensions.
Edit2: Since I can't add an answer, here is the code I made by checking the "duplicate" original one.

```dart
import 'dart:svg' as svg;
//...
DivElement div = querySelector("#mainDiv");
svg.SvgElement svgElement = new svg.SvgSvgElement();
div.append(svgElement);

Ellipse ell = new Ellipse()
..cx = 100
..cy= 100
..rx= 50
..ry= 50;

svg.ImageElement image = new svg.ImageElement();

svgElement.children.add(image);
image.setAttribute('x', '0');
image.setAttribute('y', '0');
image.setAttribute('width', '100%');
image.setAttribute('height', '100%');
image.getNamespacedAttributes('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')['href'] = '2.jpg';

svgElement.children.add(ell.ellipse);
```

Comment: Got the duplicate one, but it doesn't say how to load it as an element, for example to get the width and height.

Comment: If the duplicate question solves a part of your question then edit your question to show only your current issue i.e. loading an element.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but I assume that the `onLoad` event will not fire before the element isn't added to the DOM.
You should add the image just after creating the element.
You could alternatively set `display: none` and change to `display: auto` when onLoad fires.

Comment: I have noticed a big mistake (I think). I'm using ImageElement and not svg.ImageElement (dart:svg)